# SSJS Codes behind the button runs after page is refreshed

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have SSJS code behind a button. When i click the button that code creates a document in another database.

When i click the button It Works fine but I look at the Domino Admin COnsole I realize that The code behind to button Works twice.. I think When the page is refreshed It Works again? How can i prevent it? 
What is it thet I miss?

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">

    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("Before createNewDoc()");
createNewDoc();
print("After createNewDoc()");
}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

[image: Code view behind the button]

Comment: Please include the XML markup for the button. It may not identify the cause, but the screenshot is insufficient.

Comment: What does it mean "Please include the XML markup for the button" :( I am sorry I don't know What it means :(

Comment: I have added Whole code into my question. I think This is what you meant?

Comment: Is there any other code in other events? Can you post the markup of the whole XPage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add print statements to the `beforePageLoad`, `afterPageLoad` etc events to confirm where it is running. Also, it's worth using XPages OpenLog Logger or some other logging framework that can output a full stack trace. That might identify whether the code is running twice in the refresh, and where from.

There is no reason the code should be running twice from the button. I'm assuming this is an SSJS function in a Script Library, maybe something else is triggering that.